# Read nested JSON into Pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, json, pandas, dataframe, normalization

**Background Info -**
I have a JSON response from an API call, which I am trying to save in a pandas DataFrame, whilst maintaining the same structure, as when I view in a system I have called the data from.

**Functions that calls JSON Response -**
`def api_call():` calls the API (**Note:** `url_list` only contains 1x url at present) and saves the response in the `api_response` variable, using `json.loads(response.text)`

```
def api_call():
    url_list = url_constructor()
    for url in url_list:
        response = requests.get(url_list[0], auth = HTTPBasicAuth(key, secret), headers={"Firm":"583"})
    api_response = json.loads(response.text)
    return api_response
```

**Function that saves response to file and also returns it:**

`def response_writer():` saves `api_response` as a JSON file. It also returns `api_response`.

```
def response_writer():
    api_response = api_call()
    timestr = datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%Y-%m-%d-%H:%M")
    filename = 'api_response_'+timestr+'.json'
    with open(filename, 'w') as output_data:
        json.dump(api_response, output_data)
        print("-------------------------------------------------------\n", 
              "API RESPONSE SAVED:", filename, "\n-------------------------------------------------------")
    return api_response
```

**JSON Response -**

```
{
  "meta": {
    "columns": [
      {
        "key": "node_id",
        "display_name": "Entity ID",
        "output_type": "Word"
      },
      {
        "key": "bottom_level_holding_account_number",
        "display_name": "Holding Account Number",
        "output_type": "Word"
      },
      {
        "key": "value",
        "display_name": "Adjusted Value (USD)",
        "output_type": "Number",
        "currency": "USD"
      },
      {
        "key": "node_ownership",
        "display_name": "% Ownership",
        "output_type": "Percent"
      },
      {
        "key": "model_type",
        "display_name": "Model Type",
        "output_type": "Word"
      },
      {
        "key": "valuation",
        "display_name": "Valuation (USD)",
        "output_type": "Number",
        "currency": "USD"
      },
      {
        "key": "_custom_jb_custodian_305769",
        "display_name": "JB Custodian",
        "output_type": "Word"
      },
      {
        "key": "top_level_owner",
        "display_name": "Top Level Owner",
        "output_type": "Word"
      },
      {
        "key": "top_level_legal_entity",
        "display_name": "Top Level Legal Entity",
        "output_type": "Word"
      },
      {
        "key": "direct_owner",
        "display_name": "Direct Owner",
        "output_type": "Word"
      },
      {
        "key": "online_status",
        "display_name": "Online Status",
        "output_type": "Word"
      },
      {
        "key": "financial_service",
        "display_name": "Financial Service",
        "output_type": "Word"
      },
      {
        "key": "_custom_placeholder_461415",
        "display_name": "Placeholder or Fee Basis",
        "output_type": "Boolean"
      },
      {
        "key": "_custom_close_date_411160",
        "display_name": "Account Close Date",
        "output_type": "Date"
      },
      {
        "key": "_custom_ownership_audit_note_425843",
        "display_name": "Ownership Audit Note",
        "output_type": "Word"
      }
    ],
    "groupings": [
      {
        "key": "holding_account",
        "display_name": "Holding Account"
      }
    ]
  },
  "data": {
    "type": "portfolio_views",
    "attributes": {
      "total": {
        "name": "Total",
        "columns": {
          "direct_owner": null,
          "node_ownership": null,
          "online_status": null,
          "_custom_ownership_audit_note_425843": null,
          "model_type": null,
          "_custom_placeholder_461415": null,
          "top_level_owner": null,
          "_custom_close_date_411160": null,
          "valuation": null,
          "bottom_level_holding_account_number": null,
          "_custom_jb_custodian_305769": null,
          "financial_service": null,
          "top_level_legal_entity": null,
          "value": null,
          "node_id": null
        },
        "children": [
          {
            "entity_id": 4754837,
            "name": "Apple Holdings Adv (748374923)",
            "grouping": "holding_account",
            "columns": {
              "direct_owner": "Apple Holdings LLC",
              "node_ownership": 1,
              "online_status": "Online",
              "_custom_ownership_audit_note_425843": null,
              "model_type": "Holding Account",
              "_custom_placeholder_461415": false,
              "top_level_owner": "Forsyth Family",
              "_custom_close_date_411160": null,
              "valuation": 10423695.609450001,
              "bottom_level_holding_account_number": "748374923",
              "_custom_jb_custodian_305769": "Laverockbank",
              "financial_service": "laverockbankcustodianservice",
              "top_level_legal_entity": "Apple Holdings LLC",
              "value": 10423695.609450001,
              "node_id": "4754837"
            },
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  },
  "included": []
}
```

**Expected structure of JSON in Pandas DataFrame -**
This is the structure I am trying to convey in my pandas DataFrame -

```
| Holding Account                 | Entity ID | Holding Account Number | Adjusted Value (USD) | % Ownership | Model Type      | Valuation (USD) | JB Custodian | Top Level Owner | Top Level Legal Entity          | Direct Owner                    | Online Status | Financial Service   | Placeholder or Fee Basis | Account Close Date | Ownership Audit Note |
|---------------------------------|-----------|------------------------|----------------------|-------------|-----------------|-----------------|--------------|-----------------|---------------------------------|---------------------------------|---------------|---------------------|--------------------------|--------------------|----------------------|
| Apple Holdings Adv (748374923)  | 4754837   | 748374923              | $10,423,695.06       | 100.00%     | Holding Account | $10,423,695.06  | BRF          | Forsyth Family  | Apple Holdings Partners LLC     | Apple Holdings Partners LLC     | Online        | custodianservice    | No                       | -                  | -                    |
```

**My interpretation of the JSON Structure -**
It looks like I need to concentrate on `{'columns:` (which has the column headers), and the `'children'` (which represent rows of data, in my case, just 1x row) of `'data':`. I can ignore `'groupings': [{'key': 'holding_account', 'display_name': 'Holding Account'}]},`, as this ultimately is how the data sorted in the system.

Does anyone have advice on how I might take the JSON and load into a DataFrame with the demonstrated structure?

My interpretation is that I need to set the `display_names` [`columns`] as headers and then map the respective `children` values under each respective `display_names` / headers. **Note:** Ordinarily, there would be more `children` (representing each line of data for my DataFrame), however I have stripped all but 1x out, to make it easier to interpret.

Comment: Check out Glom (https://pypi.org/project/glom) which can help you format the data into the format needed and then use Pandas to create a dataframe from that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest using `pd.json_normalize()` ( https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/1.2.0/reference/api/pandas.json_normalize.html ) which helps transform JSON data into a pandas DataFrame.

*Note 1:* Following I assume the data is available in a python dictionary called `data`. For testing purpose I used

```
import json
json_data = '''
{
  "meta": {
      # ....
  },
  #...
  "included": []
}
'''
data = json.loads(json_data)
```

where `json_data` is your JSON response. As `json.loads()` doesn't accept a final comma, I omitted the comma after the children object.

`pd.json_normalize()` offers different options. One possibility is to simply read all "children" data and then drop the columns that are not required. Also, after normalizing some columns have a prefix "columns." which needs to be removed.

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.json_normalize(data['data']['attributes']['total']['children'])
df.drop(columns=['grouping', 'entity_id'], inplace=True)
df.columns = df.columns.str.replace(r'columns.', '')
```

Finally, the columns names need to be replaced with those in the "columns" data:

```
column_name_mapper = {column['key']: column['display_name'] for column in data['meta']['columns']}
df.rename(columns=column_name_mapper, inplace=True)
```

*Note 2:* There are some slight deviations from the expected structure you described. Most notably the word 'name' (with the row value "Apple Holdings Adv (748374923)") in the data frame header is not changed to 'Holding Account' as both terms are not found in the columns list. Some other values simply differ between the described JSON response and the expected structure.

Comment: Thank you for your contribution. I created a function which returns the api response and stores in 'api_response' and then tried 'data = json.loads(api_response)'. However, I get a 'TypeError: the JSON object must be str, bytes or bytearray, not dict' message. Any ideas why?

Comment: `json.loads()` expects a str, bytes or bytearray... So I actually passed the JSON response as a string to the function (using triple quotes as it spans multiple lines). I clarified that part in the answer. This worked for testing. Still, in your specific context some other solution is probably more appropriate, depending on how you receive the json from the API call.

Comment: Thanks rosa - I misread I'm afraid. Thanks for the great explanation; I have learnt a lot!

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure this is the best way to unpack a dictionary, but it works:
(It's used to keep the child "metadata" like the id (duplicate), and holding account full name)

```
def unpack_dict(item, out):
    for k, v in item.items():
        if type(v) == dict:
            unpack_dict(v, out)
        else:
            out[k] = v
    return out
```

Now we need to use this on every single child to get the data

From your example, it seems like you want to keep the Holding account (from child), but you don't want the entity_id, as it is duplicated in node_id?

Not sure, so I'll just include all columns with their "raw" names

```
columns = unpack_dict(res["data"]["attributes"]["total"]["children"][0]
children = res["data"]["attributes"]["total"]["children"]
data = []

for i in children:
    data.append(list(unpack_dict(i, {}).values()))
```

And creating a dataframe from that:

```
>>> pd.DataFrame(data=data, columns = columns)
   entity_id                            name  ...         value  node_id
0    4754837  Apple Holdings Adv (748374923)  ...  1.042370e+07  4754837

[1 rows x 18 columns]
```

This can be now altered to have the display names instead of these raw ones. You might need to remove some columns though, as I mentioned above, the id is duplicated, you mentioned grouping etc.

If you are dealing with large amounts of data (thousands of entries) and it takes long time to parse it, the excessive columns can be removed before inserting into `data` to save some time later on.

To rename a columns using a `dict`:

```
df.rename(columns={'oldName1': 'newName1', 'oldName2': 'newName2'})
```

Comment: Many thanks for your contribution. Your explanation makes sense, however can you give context on how to integrate this function into my code? The API response is stored in a variable called 'api_response' Note: I have inc. the functions that call and store the API response in my question.

Comment: @William right, instead of using `res` use your `api_response` and it should work, since it's a `dict`

Comment: Thanks for confirming. Also, how should this be structured i.e., the placement of the 'def unpack_dict(item, out):' function and proceeding code you mentioned? I'm just trying to understand how to piece together, so I can learn and understand how it works and of course test!

Comment: @William yes, you can just place it one after another, and then with the final `pd.DataFrame(data=data, columns = columns)` you will get the dataframe table